# parallel.foreach and insertonsubmit primarykey issue

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement `a parallel.foreach` that inside of it has an `InsertOnSubmit`

Most of the time everything works fine, but every so often I get an exception:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint - Cannot insert duplicate key

I've tried it with different parallelOptions and it isn't consistant.  I am not using the same DataContext for each iteration of the loop, is there any suggestions for using `InsertOnSubmit` from within a `parallel.foreach` loop?

```
while (myConcurrentDictionary.Count > 0)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(myConcurrentDictionary, pOptions, (KVP, loopState) =>
    {
        pOptions.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        passCount++;
        MsgLog.WriteLine(KVP.Key);
        processKVP(KVP.Key, KVP.Value, loopState);
    }); //End of Parallel.ForEach loop
}


processKVP()
{
    ...
    DCtxt myDC = new DCtxt();

    myDC.TABLE.InsertOnSubmit(new TABLE
    {
       ...
    });
    insertCount++;

    if ((insertCount % 100) == 0)
    {
      myDC.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the foreach code?

Comment: You're using non-thread-safe objects.  Don't do that.

Comment: Are you using a new data context for each iteration, or are you trying to ensure synchronized access to each one without doing that?  If the former, it's a more fundamental problem with your DB schema or the DB itself.  If the later, you just aren't doing it properly and shouldn't bother doing that to begin with.

Comment: What array/collection are you looping through ? do you have duplicates ?

Comment: @SLaks Well, he says, "I am not using the same DataContext for each iteration of the loop", which seems to indicate he knows that the data context isn't thread safe.

Comment: You've posted your code, but it doesn't really do anything interesting except call a method you didn't show the definition of.  `processKVP` is likely where your bug is.

Comment: In the very little code we see, you are incrementing a variable called `passCount` which is not thread-local. So it could very well be corrupted by multiple threads. You'd do better replacing that line with `Interlocked.Increment(ref passCount);`

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - I should NOT have duplicates in my concurrentDictionary

Comment: And now ditto for the increment of `insertCount`, but you will want to use the return value of it for your if statement, which should look like `if ((Interlocked.Increment(ref insertCount) % 100) == 0)` and eliminate the prior increment.

Comment: Also, since `DCtxt` is an Entity Framework `DataContext`, you should be wrapping it in a `using` statement since the aforementioned superclass implements `IDisposable`. You may even want to take it out of your `processKVP` method and put it just outside your `while` of the caller and pass it to the `processKVP` method.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I am creating a new insertCount for each iteration (i.e. Int32 insertCount = 0;)  Do I need an interlock around every variable in my method?

Comment: @JeffV if `insertCount` is a class member (which it looks like due to the code sample), yes, you do, as that method can be called from multiple concurrent threads.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer He most certainly *does not* want to move the scope of the data context as you described.  It's not designed to be used by multiple threads, as I and Slacks have said, and making your change would introduce a *significant* threading bug.  It should indeed be in a `using` (although that is not the source of the bug), but it should also stay right where it is.

Comment: @Servy then this thing needs some serious redesign from the ground up since he wants the data context to only commit the inserts for every 100 accumulations of TABLE objects.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer How so?  Those 100 inserts are only ever the result of that one thread touching the data context; there are simply N other data contexts in other threads preparing 100 item batches at the same time.  It's not until the DB receives those batches that it should be assigning the identifier, and DBs are built to support stuff like this.  If he's managing his own primary key then that's likely his bug, and the fix is not to do that; it's hard, let the DB do it for you.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer - Where can I get more information on when and where to use the Interlocked keyword.  Is it only regarding the database inserts or do I have to use it for every string and int in my method?

Comment: @Servy I'm only seeing precisely one insert per created data context in the `processKVP` method. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JeffV the `Interlocked` static class is primarily used for numbers, but it has many other uses, too. Check out the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx

Comment: @Servy it looks like you are right.  I thought the column in question was an identity column... but it isn't.  I'll have to find out the context as to why it wasn't an identity column.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the bug was on this one.  The application is calling a webservice which creates files with time stamps which was the cause of this issue.  Because I was calling the web service in parallel I had multiple files that were created at the same time.

So by creating a time stamp that was increased to the hundred thousandths this issue is corrected:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmssfffff")`

Thanks for everyone's comments on this.